# Regular expression to validate comma separated email addresses

Tags: regex, validation, email, jquery-validation-engine

I am supposed to validate comma separated email addresses and avoid invalid patterns like

```
email..email@domain.com,
.email@domain.com,
email@domain.web,
email.@domain.com,
email@-domain.com,
email@domain.web,
email@111.222.333.44444
```

currently I am using following Regular expression

`regex = /^((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.([a-zA-Z])+([-.]\w+)*)*([,])*)*$/`

(custom regex rule as in validation-engine)

For which I can not use `email@domain99.com` which can be a valid email address in my case
Please suggest me suitable answer!

EDIT-    `regex = /^((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.([a-zA-Z])+([-.]\w+)*)* ([,])*)*$/`  this expression miserably failed when I used **,,** instead of **,** to separate the values. Suggest a way please.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't much use for this. Split on the comma, try to email each on, handle bounces however you want.

Comment: Read [I Know How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read the RFC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/) - e-mail validation is quite a challenge !

Comment: @marc_s  I am concerned about how it(regex) works for me. and thanks for the nice read.

Comment: @jonrsharpe as per the requirements of project I am handling these validations on client side only. I am not going for my server soide c# yet. Splitting and validating separating
My prime concern is my regex **Blocks**  `email@domain99.com` , which I **don't want** to. Yet I want to disallow `email@111.222.333.44444`

Comment: Well then just search for a more accurate regex; there are dozens of questions already here and resources elsewhere on the internet covering it.